# Variable lengths differ (found for 'chemdate')

Tags: r

I'm running lm and ANOVA for a dataset and I keep getting the "variable lengths differ (found for '...')" error, but my data columns are the same length. Any ideas?

I've already renamed and checked through to see if theres anything awry. 
My data is just sets of columns with 82 data points in each.

```
chemlm0 <- lm(N ~ chemdate+Lineage+chemdate:Lineage, data=subset(chem, eggs==1 & Lineage %in% c('old','new')))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = N ~ chemdate + Lineage + chemdate:Lineage,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'chemdate')
```

Comment: Try passing `lm()` the full data.frame and using the inbuilt subset argument. As an aside, you could also simplify your formula to `N ~ chemdate*Lineage`.

Comment: is there any chance that you'd be able to expand on this? Coding is not my strong point and I'm unsure of what an inbuilt subset argument is. Thankyou so much!

Comment: Try: `lm(N ~ chemdate * Lineage, data = chem, subset = (eggs == 1 & Lineage %in% c('old', 'new')))`